# AutoitX.Send is not sending Keystrokes to text field in Windows Sever using C#

Tags: c#, selenium, autoit-c#-wrapper

I am using AutoitX.Send(Filepath) to upload a file in server.

I have written below code

```
AutoItX.WinActivate("Open");
AutoItX.ControlFocus("[Class:Edit]","", "Edit1");
Thread.Sleep(5000);
Log.Info("FILEPATH BEFORE SEND KEY" + filePath);
AutoItX.Send(filePath);
AutoItX.Send("{Enter}");
```

This code works in my local, but it's not working on the server.

I am getting the error for find element, which can be found once the upload file is successful, but autoitx.send is not sending any keystroke to file explorer to find specific file.

Can someone please help me on this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include specific information about the error you are getting and your desired behavior.

Comment: I am trying to upload a file after clicking on browse button in application, so I was using autoitx.send to pass the file path and upload it. this is working fine in local but in server it is not writing filepath in text field and failing to find the next element which loads after uploading a file

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include this information. It gets lost in comments too easily.